# Protect multi tenant web API with azure AD

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory

I'm new to azure active directory and would like to understand how to secure a multi tenant client app and API.

The scenario I would like to understand as an example is, if the API had an action `getcompany` the the client app should be allowed to call this on behalf of the signed in user, assigned a `company read role`.

However an action say that lists all companies signed up should only ever be allowed to be called by a user with relevant role from with in my AAD tenant.

How can I apply such restrictions? What is to prevent someone else writing a client and assigning their app with roles then gaining access to my Api.

Answer (score 1):

> prevent someone else writing a client and assigning their app with
> roles

If you integrate azure ad into your application, you also need to set the authentication application's information(client id, client secret, etc.) into your app's configuration, so even someone elso knows your role name, they still aren't able to create their own azure ad app to authenticate.

> should only ever be allowed to be called by a user with relevant role

As you know we usually use access token to protect the api, and in azure ad, what we usually do is exposing an api(with a delegate app permission) then generate access token with this scope, in the backend api, authorize the token if contains that scope.

But in your scenario, you also require to check if this user has enough permission to `get all companies`, so you think you need to validate user role too. To tell you the truth, [azure ad access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) doesn't contain a claim for user role, only the id token contains user role. So I recommend you to make all the allowed users join a security group. Then when you decode the jwt access token, you can check the `groups` claim to check if the user has enough permission.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The client secret prevents someone using the existing app registration, but what is to stop someone creating a new app registration and adding known roles, then calling the multi tenant API?

Comment: multi-tenant api make an azure ad application can used to generate access token for several tenants, but if this application is registered in one tenent, but this tenant is not your tenant, then this app need admin permission in your tenant then can be used to generate token for calling your  api, or you can know as, if an azure ad app in other tenant wanna used to generate access token to call api managed in your tenant, then it need to be registered in your tenant first, you can see these azure ad app in enterprise app blade. @BeginnerDBADan